# How to implement a TCP traffic limitation for the sender side?

Tags: c++, tcp, limit, traffic

I'm about to implement a webcam video chat system for multiple users in C++ (windows/linux). As the 'normal' user is usually connected via DSL/cable, there is a strong bandwidth limitation for my (prefered) TCP/IP connections.

The basic idea is to transmit the highest possible framerate given a bandwidth limitation for the sender side. (Other applications may still require internet bandwidth in the background.) In a second step, the camera-capture-rate shall be automatically adjusted to the network limitations to avoid unncessary CPU overhead.

What I have is a constant stream of compressed images (with strongly variing buffer sizes) that have to be transmitted to the remote side. Given a limitation of let's say 20kb/s, how do I best implement that limitation? (Note that the user shall define this limit!)

Thx in advance,
Mayday

Edit: Question clearifications (sry!)

- It's about how to traffic-shape an arbitrary TCP/IP connection.
- It's **not** how to implement image rate/quality reduction as my use-case suggests. (Altough I didn't consider to automatically adjust image compression, yet. (Thx Jon))

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to reduce your bandwidth:

1. Send smaller images (more compression)
2. Send less images

When implementing an algorithm that picks image size and quantity to honor the user-selected limit, you have to balance between a simple/robust algorithm and a performant algorithm (one that makes maximum use out of the limit).

The first approach I would try is to use a rolling average of the bandwidth you are using at any point in time to "seed" your algorithm. Every once in a while, check the average. If it becomes more than your limit, instruct the algorithm to use less (in proportion to how much you overstepped the limit). If it becomes significantly lower than your limit, say less than 90%, instruct the algorithm to use more.

The less/more instruction might be a variable (maybe `int` or `float`, really there is much scope for inventiveness here) used by your algorithm to decide:

1. How often to capture an image and send it
2. How hard to compress that image

Comment: The idea is to automatically adjust the amount of images (with a given compression rate) given the speed of the network socket writer. Meaning that the connection shall not affect images sizes/compression ratios etc.

Comment: Ok, you're right: the adjustment-algorithm could affect both: image rate and quality.... I propably have to clearify my question: I was hoping that the TCP socket writer could reduce the traffic by itself (i.e. by stalling the send-queue) in order to reach it's traffic limitations. This way, it would stay transparent to the data it transmits...

Comment: @Mayday: well, just forget I said anything about compression then. But if the only thing you can change is the FPS of the images, you are not going to have a good granularity. Especially if the bandwidth limits are low!

Comment: You could also send fewer images, or images less frequently.

Comment: Stalling the send queue will do you no good if the thing stuffing things into the queue (your algorithm) doesn't ever slow down.

Comment: @Jon: I considered FPS to be a float-value... thus no problem with granularity!?

Comment: @Mayday: FPS is an abstraction (average over time). You can't really send 0.42 of a frame over the network. So if e.g. all frames are 8KB and your limit is 20, you will either have to stay at 16KB/sec or choose between 16 and 24 for any given one second interval. That's what I meant "low granularity".

Comment: @Jon: I wanted to send 5 frames in 2 seconds, if my limit is 20 and one frame is 8kb of size. I may not be able to adjust the capture-device in that granularity but I want to tell the network not to send more than 20kb/s...

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why not capture and encode a video stream?

Answer (score 0):

You need a buffer / queue of at least 3 frames:

- One frame currently being sent to the network;
- One complete frame to be sent next;
- One frame currently being copied from the camera.

When the network sender finishes sending a frame, it copies the "to be sent next" frame to the "currently sending" slot.  When the camera reader finishes copying a frame from the camera, it replaces the "to be sent next" frame with the copied frame.  (Obviously, synchronisation is required around the "to be sent next" frame).

The sender can then modulate its sending rate as it sees fit.  If it's running slower than the camera, it will simply drop frames.

Comment: That sounds very good! But.. how can I modulate the sending rate of a TCP connection?

Comment: @Mayday: By controlling how frequently you call `send()`.  For example, if you just sent a 75kB frame, and you want to limit the sending rate to 20kB/s, you have to sleep for 75/20 = 3.75 seconds before sending the next frame.